Generate URL in ASP.NET Core given URL path and route values
If I have a "page name" or "route name", and also route values, then I could create a URL in various ways:
return RedirectToPage
return RedirectToRoute
Url.Action
Url.ActionLink
Url.Link
Url.PageLink
Url.RouteUrl
LinkGenerator.GetPathByAction
LinkGenerator.GetPathByName
LinkGenerator.GetPathByPage
LinkGenerator.GetPathByRouteValues
LinkGenerator.GetUriByAction
LinkGenerator.GetUriByName
LinkGenerator.GetUriByPage
LinkGenerator.GetUriByRouteValues

But suppose I already have a URL path (e.g. /customer/edit) and route values (an anonymous object or a dictionary, e.g. id which equals 1) then how do I create a URL? I can't use return Redirect(path) as it doesn't support route values.
I'm looking for a RedirectXXX("/customer/edit", new { id = 1, name = "foo" }) method, if one exists. I'm surprised I could find so many overrides for so many use cases, but not one for the simplest use case.
(Yes, I can write my own, but I'm assuming something like this already exists; does it?)

A workaround, which could be put into an abstract base class like PageModelBase:
public RedirectResult Redirect(string urlPath, IDictionary<string, string?> routeValues)
{
  // ...input validation elided
  var urlFull = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(urlPath, routeValues);
  return Redirect(urlFull);
}

However, I prefer a built-in solution, which also caters for an anonymous object (instead of a dictionary) without JSON (de)serialisation hacks.
If there is such a thing, please post it and I'll accept your answer.
